# count sum 1/1+1/2+1/3+1/n series

Tags: c++, recursion, sum, series

I have to count sum 1/1+1/2+1/3+1/4+1/n series using recursion. I have tried this but it does not work. how should I solve it?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
double sum(int n)
{
  if(n==1){return 1;}
  if(n==0){return 0;}
  return 1+1/sum(n-1);
}
int main(){
  cout<<sum(2);
}
```

Comment: What does not work? Did you try to step through your code line to line with a debugger?

Comment: Is the desired sum a continued fraction, or a sum of simple fractions?

Comment: You're code is calculating `1 + 1/(1 + 1/(1 + 1/...))`, which isn't the same as `1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3`

Comment: Why do you want to use recursion? This is dead simple with a for loop.

Comment: what should I change guys?

Comment: @PeteBecker Yea I know but I have to do.

Comment: @YoungCoder Maybe start with a simple for loop, and then convert that into recursion. That should help you see why you're current code is calculating the wrong thing.

Comment: @YoungCoder what will be in the denominator after the first recursion?

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out in the comments, the formula in your function results in another series than the intended [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)). [Here, a possible solution](https://onlinegdb.com/rJwUzWEQO):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double sum_recursive(int n)
{
    if (n <= 0) {
        return 0.0;
    } else {
        cout << "1/" << n << (n!=1 ? " + " : " = "); // just for debugging
        return (1.0 / double(n)) + sum_recursive(n-1);
    }
}

double sum_iterative(int n)
{
    double v = 0.0;
    if (n <= 0) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    for (int i=n; i>0; --i) {
        v += 1.0 / double(i);
        cout << "1/" << i << (i!=1 ? " + " : " = "); // just for debugging
    }
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    const int x = 4;
    cout << sum_iterative(x) << " (iterative)" << endl;
    cout << sum_recursive(x) << " (recursive)" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Console:

```
$ g++ test_seq.c && ./a.out
1/4 + 1/3 + 1/2 + 1/1 = 2.08333 (iterative)                                                                                                                                         
1/4 + 1/3 + 1/2 + 1/1 = 2.08333 (recursive)
```

Assuming this is just used as an exercise, it should be noted, that a recursive solution doesn't have any apparent advantages over a simple loop...

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can approach this. While recursive functions can provide elegant solutions for some problem where a non-recursive approach is difficult, recursion in general should not be your first choice. Why? Each recursive call is a separate function call that requires the setup and resources of a complete function stack. If you recurse too many times, you will actually learn about StackOverflow...

That said, learning recursive functions are a necessary part of learning to program. Here the number of recursive calls is limited to `n` so you are safe. Every recursive function has two things:

1. an exit condition that stops the recursion; and
2. a recursive call.

You want to preserve a sum over your recursive calls. A `static` variable initialized on its first declaration will do. So in this case, you can do something like:

```cpp
double sum (int n)
{
    static double val = 0.;
    
    if (n) {
        val += 1. / n;
        sum (n - 1);
    }
    
    return val;
}
```

The scheme above is relatively simple. You use a check for a positive value for `n` as your exit condition, and each time you make a recursive call you reduce the value of `n` by 1. If you want to see how your recursion is progressing, you can add debug output between the update of `val` and the recursive call to `sum (n - 1)` such as:

```
        std::cout << "n:" << n << "  frac: 1/" << n << "  val: " << val << '\n';
```

A short example that takes the first argument to the program as `n` could be:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

double sum (int n)
{
    static double val = 0.;
    
    if (n) {
        val += 1. / n;
        sum (n - 1);
    }
    
    return val;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    /* initialize with 1st argument to program (default: 2) */
    std::string s { argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "2" };
    int n;
    
    try {                                   /* stoi must have exception handler */
        n = stoi (s);                       /* attempt conversion */
        std::cout << sum (n) << '\n';       /* output result */
    }
    catch (const std::exception & e) {      /* catch exception return error */
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

The resulting values for `n` from `0` to `20` would be:

```
$ for i in {0..20}; do printf "%2d  " $i; ./bin/frac_sum_recurse $i; done
 0  0
 1  1
 2  1.5
 3  1.83333
 4  2.08333
 5  2.28333
 6  2.45
 7  2.59286
 8  2.71786
 9  2.82897
10  2.92897
11  3.01988
12  3.10321
13  3.18013
14  3.25156
15  3.31823
16  3.38073
17  3.43955
18  3.49511
19  3.54774
20  3.59774
```

While you are building good habits learning C++, have a look at: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696). Here it would save no more than three `std::`.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Just to get the terminology right: stack frame != full stack.

Comment: Is `if (n)` still considered good practice for C++? It feels flaky relying on the binary representation of the integer value of 0 being the same as for the boolean value false.

Comment: @EricJ. It's really six-to-one, a half-dozen-to-another. `if (n)` is simply shorthand for `if (n == 0)`. (or int the case of a pointer, `NULL` or `nullptr`). There is no prohibition to using either, but for readability, there is an argument that `n == 0` form is more explicitly readable.